# Vim keeps changing expandtab

Tags: vim

Sometimes Vim keeps changing my `expandtab` settings. I want spaces always for specific file types but sometimes, when I insert a new line, it gives me a tab instead.

```
verb set expandtab?
```

Tells me `nonexpandtab` was set in this file:

```
set autoindent
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set numberwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set smartindent
autocmd FileType ruby,php,vim,jade,erb,css,scss,html,coffee,javascript setlocal expandtab sw=2 sts=2
au FileType xml exe ":silent 1,$!XMLLINT_INDENT='    ' xmllint --format --recover - 2>/dev/null"
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" Command to set how many spaces
command! -nargs=1 SetSpace call s:SetSpace(<f-args>)
function! s:SetSpace(space)
  setlocal expandtab sta
  let &sw = a:space
  let &sts = a:space
endfunction
```

Where exactly did it `set noexpandtab` ?

**Update**
I notice that this problem happens when I enter a new line and if the line happens to be indented as 8 spaces then Vim converts to a tab. How to fix this?

Comment: What file is this? Your vimrc? A ftplugin? Something else?

Comment: It's in my `.vimrc`. It's a separate file I source in `.vimrc`

Comment: Can you post your vim configuration? (github or something)

Answer (score 2):

The `:verbose set` unfortunately doesn't capture *all* instances, so it may give no or a wrong answer.

Alternatively, you can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect commands.

Comment: It happens quite randomly. I tried to log Vim session but it crashed. I did a grep for noexpand and the only thing I got was `setlocal noexpandtab` in a function, which won't be called unless I call it specifically. Do you know what other commands that could affect tab/space setting?

Comment: It has to be through `:set[local]`, or an equivalent function.